# Incorrect time on Windows

Tags: windows-8, time-zone

The time that Windows displays is two hours later than the actual time. The time zone is correctly configured to UTC+2 (that's my location's time zone). I've tried setting the time zone to UTC and that has caused Windows to display the correct time, but it also caused other applications (such as Gmail) to display an incorrect time.

I'm using Windows 8. How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just set the time zone correctly (to that of your location) and then change your system time to the correct one. The time zone setting is only there to provide correct translation to UTC and proper DST detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time zone is set correctly, maybe simply the system time is simply 2 hours out...

Once you have set the time zone to the correct one (or don't bother if it is correct) Try going to time settings and manually changing the time to the correct one.